# qemu aarch64 gicv3 memory-mapped registers can't be modified

Tags: qemu, arm64

According to the info in generated dtb, the memory-mapped registers of gicv3-distributor have a base addr, which is `0x0800_0000`.

And I have checked the validity by reading gicd_typer, which means the base addr is right.
But when I want to configure the gicv3-distributor (like changing `GICD_ICACTIVER<n>`), the value is not changed, keeping the default value. The same thing happens on any register of GICD in my machine.
I change them with **assembly code** as soon as the machine starts, **not enable MMU**.

```
    ldr x8, =0x8000380 
    ldr x9, =0xffffffff
    str x9, [x8]
    dsb sy
    ldr x0, [x8]
(gdb) i r x0
x0             0x0      0
```

**Even I write to this memory by gdb `set` command, the value is also unchangeable.**

The addr of `GICD_ICACTIVER<n>` should be `0x0800_0380`(offset=0x380), which should be readable and writable, isn't it?

> The UART(`pl011`)-related address(`0x0900_0000`) can be written normally.

- Host machine: Ubuntu 18.04
- qemu version: 7.1.50 (v7.1.0-256-g79dfa177)
- Target OS: bare-metal
- qemu command:

```
./qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3,secure=on,virtualization=on -cpu cortex-a76 -m 1G
```

Comment: Finally, I found out that it was about ARMv8's secure state.  Registers have different behavior in different secure states. And it's my mistake to miss the option `secure=on` in question description. When I remove it, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The GICD_ICACTIVER register bits are write-1-to-clear, so if you write all-1s to the register then you should expect it to read back as all-0s.

More generally, not all hardware device registers will read back the same value that you write to them -- it depends entirely on the device.

Comment: So is there any register of GIC distributor that can be write&read-back to check whether the memory write is successful?

Comment: I have tested so many registers. Excluding `GICD_CTLR/TYPER/IIDR`, other registers have default value 0. And writing to **all GICD registers** will be ignored.

Comment: Linux can boot and use the GICv3, so the chances are extremely high that there's a problem in your code, not in the GIC model. And yes, most GIC registers reset to zero -- that's the way the GIC specification says they behave.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I miss the `secure=on` in question description. And I found out that I can't modify the register because I was in a wrong secure state. That's a problem with secure state switching.

Comment: But very thanks for the answer. The wrong register is one of my mistakes. I select `GICD_IPRIORITYR<n>` for new write&read-back test. It's work.